# data table column misalignment in edge

Tags: jquery, html, css, microsoft-edge, datatables-1.10

I am using datatable plugin. But in edge browser i get column misalignment.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
              destroy: true,
              paging: false,
              info: false,
              stateSave: true,
              bStateSave: true,
              dom: 't',
              'scrollX': true,
    } );
} );
```

Here is the plunk link- https://plnkr.co/edit/rNHLC6gqSJDgdhkvNCa6?p=preview

I am using 'scrollX' to get responsitivity. If I remove scroll X the column alignment seems to be fine. Any leads will be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the `td` and the `th` to `white-space: nowrap` in your CSS seems to fix this issue in edge.

```
  table.dataTable tbody th,
  table.dataTable tbody td {
      white-space: nowrap;
  }
```

[Here is a fork of your plunker with the proposed change](https://plnkr.co/edit/OTSchwe9U0lQOcJlwkJy?p=preview)

Comment: Your fix works, but it's not usable in my case - I have to have wrapping in some of my columns in order to get the content to fit in a reasonable space. The columns start drifting out of alignment after the first column with wrapping. I spotted this reported as an Issue on the Datatables GITHUB, but no solution there: https://github.com/DataTables/DataTables/issues/893